# Why we turn off anti-ice first then put on APU bleed after parking?

Tags: airbus-a320, apu, anti-ice

In A320 Standard Operation Procedure (Parking procedure), the order of parking procedure is anti- ice off then APU bleed as required. Is there any meaning for this order? Can’t we switch the order instead? If there is any relation based on system relationship, I would like to know.

Comment: Is A320 anti-ice electric - if so, then this'd be to reduce the load at switch over to ground power / APU off ...?  Covered at [page 41 of the A320 normal procedures](https://www.theairlinepilots.com/forumarchive/a320/a320-normal-procedures.pdf)

Comment: @MrR No, it's not electric. I think the 787 is the only jet airliner that uses electric thermal anti-ice. All others use bleed air.

Comment: The "dupe" question is about Wing A/I; this question sounds like it's about Engine A/I. Is that not correct?

Comment: @RalphJ I thought Engine A/I is separate from the rest of the bleed system, but I can't find a diagram to prove it. Anyway, OP should probably clarify which anti ice system they mean.

Comment: @RalphJ: nope, engine AI on the 320 can only be supplied by the engine itself (dedicated bleed stage)

Answer (score 6):

The SOP calls for

```
ANTI-ICE ... OFF
APU BLEED pb-sw ... ON
```

the former covers *both* wing and engine anti-ice.

It is not allowed to use APU bleed for wing anti-icing, as defined in FCOM Limitations. (FCOM-LIM-APU-OPERATIONAL ENVELOPE)

As APU bleed has priority over engine bleeds the wing anti-ice valves have to be closed before APU bleed valve is opened.

For engine anti-icing the order does not really matter. Each engine uses its' own closed system for anti-icing with dedicated bleed valves.

Comment: Since each engine’s anti-ice is a local system, does that mean that if the engine shuts down for any reason and could be restarted later, there’ll be no anti-icing for that engine in the meantime? Has this ever caused a problem? (I doubt but curious)

Comment: Yes, since each engine anti-ices its own nacelle. Never heard it being a problem, but should engine fail in severe icing (especially if it flames out due ice) it is likely that it will not start again.